# Matrix Routing API and traffic conditions

Tags: routes, traffic

How TrafficMode attribute affects the results of Matrix Routing at calculatematrix endpoint?
Let's take a look at the example:
https://developer.here.com/enterprise/apiexplorer/examples/api-for-rest/enterprise-routing/calculate-matrix.html
I've tried to compare results with the option traffic:enabled and disabled, but result is the same in both cases on different locations.
According to the reference: "BaseTime" is the property that holds the total route travel time, taking into account the mode of transport, but not traffic information.
How can I get the time considering traffic conditions?

I've also tried to run "Car Routing" example:
https://developer.here.com/enterprise/apiexplorer/examples/api-for-rest/enterprise-routing/car-route-from-a-to-b-ent.html
The response contains "TrafficTime" property, but it has the same value as "BaseTime" despite of the option traffic:enabled or disabled.

So the question is how to get traffic time considering current traffic information?

P.S.: I've tried to run following requests for calculatematrix:

```
https://route.st.nlp.nokia.com/routing/6.2/calculatematrix.json?mode=shortest%3Bcar%3Btraffic%3Aenabled&start0=40.7790%2C-73.9622&destination0=40.7482%2C-73.9860&destination1=40.7558%2C-73.9870&destination2=40.7054%2C-73.9961&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg
https://route.st.nlp.nokia.com/routing/6.2/calculatematrix.json?mode=shortest%3Bcar%3Btraffic%3Adisabled&start0=40.7790%2C-73.9622&destination0=40.7482%2C-73.9860&destination1=40.7558%2C-73.9870&destination2=40.7054%2C-73.9961&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg
```

and for calculateroute:

```
https://route.st.nlp.nokia.com/routing/6.2/calculateroute.json?waypoint0=48.8416%2C2.1260&waypoint1=48.8518%2C2.3091&mode=fastest%3Bcar%3Btraffic%3Aenabled&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg
https://route.st.nlp.nokia.com/routing/6.2/calculateroute.json?waypoint0=48.8416%2C2.1260&waypoint1=48.8518%2C2.3091&mode=fastest%3Bcar%3Btraffic%3Adisabled&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg
```

For calculateroute "TrafficTime":1388.0,"BaseTime":1388.0 are the same in both cases (approx ~23 minutes). Same points on HERE Maps give 36 minutes for BaseTime and 49 minutes for TrafficTime.

```
http://here.com/directions/drive/31,_Chemin_du_Cabaret,_78620_L'%C3%89tang-la-Ville,_%D0%A4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F[48.87188435495411,2.07658168554687]/24,_Rue_Falgui%C3%A8re,_75015_%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B6,_%D0%A4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F[48.84263282360221,2.316047907763675]/@a79afc8d3ff753307872c30fb9b449ea/map=48.8520703,2.381732,12,0,0,normal.day
```

Screenshot:

```
s12.postimg.org/3xpy4h9pp/screen.png
```

Comment: Please post the code you've tried.

Comment: Look at the Playground [Traffic-based Routing Example](https://developer.here.com/enterprise/apiexplorer/examples/api-for-js/routing/route-using-traffic-information.html) to see how traffic effects the route. Remember that the time of day and distance of route will also alter the traffic conditions - don't expect hold ups  if it is midnight local time.

Comment: On the same start and finish points here.com shows 3 different routes, none of them are the same to the route shown in the Playground.

Comment: @Danila - if you check the network traffic, you will see that the example and here.com are using different API versions. The example is using **6.2** routing, whereas here.com uses the newer **7.2** routing API. The Matrix routing endpoint is currently only available with **6.2** routing, hence the linked example is more relevant.